# Why does it say cannot resolve symbol auth?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image][image]

My firebase-auth dependency is the latest version yet Android studio shows "auth" as an error. How do I solve this?

This is my build.gradle(:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 30
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.shop"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
    }
  }

 }
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'


implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Show us the error.

Comment: I mean it just says cannot resolve symbol "auth" in all the libraries imported as shown above.

Comment: Without seeing what you get, I'm afraid we cannot be much of a help.

Comment: I have attached pictures.

Comment: Please share the entire file where you have added `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'`.

Comment: I have added the code of the entire build.gradle file

Comment: What about "File -> Invalidate cache/restart" ?

Comment: I tried but it doesnt help.